# Change handlebars variable value using front end javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

My goal is to change the value of a handlebars variable using the front end JavaScript file.

BackEnd JavaScript (app.js)

```
res.render('index', { name: 'John' })
```

.hbs file

```
<button id="name" onclick="changeName()">{{name}}</button>
```

script.js (front end)

```
const changeName = () => {
// Change the value of {{name}} from 'John' to 'Bob'
}
```

I know you can do it with:

```
const changeName = () => {
document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'Bob'
}
```

But I specifically want to change the handlebars variable value because in my actual code it is a little more complex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [Block helpers handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html), in your case you can create a helper to change the name variable like this:

.hbs

```
<div class="entry">
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
 <div class="name">
  {{#nameHelper}}{{name}}{{/nameHelper}}
 </div>
</div>
```

script.js

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('nameHelper', function(options) {
return new Handlebars.SafeString(
  '<div class="name">'
  + options.fn(otherName)
  + '</div>');
});
```